# checkout commitID not working

Tags: git, bash, commit

I'm trying to checkout to write a bash script in windows to read a commit id from a textfile then checkout. As in the following steps:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
do
   cd C:/.....
   git checkout $line
done < "$1"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: The `[[ -n "$line" ]]` hack tells me you are reading from a DOS text file, which means it (and possibly also your script) uses DOS line endings. You need to change them to POSIX line endings (`\n` instead of `\r\n`) first. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info for instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. so, the only thing I had to do is opening the text file in Notepad++ and edit with EOL conversion to Unix (LF)